# Please tell me how byte value changed

Tags: java

Please anyone tell me how I got 55 answer for the below code.

```
byte myByte = 067;

System.out.println("Byte value: " + myByte);
```

I got answer as below
Byte value: 55

Thanks.

Comment: `067` is octal 67, which is decimal 55.

Answer (score 1):

`067` is octal number notation in Java (due to leading `0`).

OCT 67 = 6*8 + 7 = 55